# Making a one rep max calculator in JavaScript, not sure why my function isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I am making a one rep max calculator using the Epley Formula. When I call the function, it says it's undefined. However, I thought by using the parameters `weight` and `reps`, which have also been parsed as integers, that they would be sufficient to implement the function.

[Here is my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wtm11z1o/)

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div>
  <h2>Calculator for Epley Formula One Rep Max</h2>
  <p>Use the spaces below to type in the weight and reps for any lift to calculate any estimated 1-Rep Max using the Epley Formula:</p>
  <b>Weight</b>
  <input type="text" id="weight">
  <b>Reps</b>
  <input type="text" id="reps">
  <button id="button">Click Me</button>
  <br></br>
<hr>    
  <div id="demo">Go for it!</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var weight = parseInt($('#weight').val());
    var reps   = parseInt($('#reps').val());
    $('#demo').html("");
    function calculateMax (weight, reps) {
        weight * (1 + (reps/30))
    };
    $('#demo').html("If you can lift " + weight + " for " + reps + " reps then you have an estimated max of " + calculateMax(weight, reps) + " !");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to return the calculated value from the `calculateMax` function

```
function calculateMax(weight, reps) {
    return weight * (1 + (reps/30));
}
```

This said, I can't see why you are using a separate function for that, why not write it like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var weight = parseInt($('#weight').val());
    var reps   = parseInt($('#reps').val());
    var max = weight * (1 + (reps/30));
    $('#demo').html("If you can lift " + weight + " for " + reps + " reps then you have an estimated max of " + max + " !");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use return:

```
function calculateMax (weight, reps) {
    return weight * (1 + (reps/30))
};
```